# Print a list of numbers from largest to smallest and smallest to largest

Tags: java, sorting, java.util.scanner

How to output the values of a list by sorting them from the smallest to the biggest or from the biggest to the smallest?

```
private static final ArrayList<Double> nbAll = new ArrayList<>();

public static void test() {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {

        System.out.print("Please enter the number of notes you want to calculate : ");
        double nb = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
            double temp = scanner.nextDouble();
            nbAll.add(temp);
        }

        double temp = nbAll.stream().mapToInt(Double::intValue).sum();

        double result = temp / nb;

        System.out.println("Result : " + result);
        retry();
    }
}
```

Comment: One way is to add them all in a list and then sort them from smaller to largest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stream the list's elements, sorting them, then printing them:

```
nbAll.stream().sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```

To sort them in reverse:

```
nbAll.stream().sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it, for that you need a List?

Comment: @Mojito991 you already *have* a list: `List<Double> nbAll = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Yes, sorry I misspoke, thanks for the help it worked
is it possible for each value to add a nickname (because the values entered will correspond to the value of someone's example)
Example:
Value - Username

Comment: and if possible a classification of the different positions (first, second, third, fourth, fifth (as many positions as there are numbers for example not by writing but by numbering example) 
Example
1) Value - Username

Comment: Do you mean print each element and its position/rank after sorting?

Comment: Yes, I have created a second post related to these questions if you want  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69052156/be-able-to-enter-a-value-and-a-string-in-a-java-scanner-to-output-a-ranking

Answer (score 0):

You can call [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))

```
Collections.sort(nbAll); // ascending order
nbAll.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Then to print them in descending order, no need to resort, just start at the end and print them in reverse order.

```
for (int i = nbAll.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
   System.out.println(nbAll.get(i));
}
```